# Show textarea field in the same page with AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, magento

I trying to show the value of a textarea input while typing using **keyup** in my `showContent` div (I will add more code later).
 But I'm not good with `Ajax` and/or `JQuery` and would like some help.

The form in `formPage.phtml` (I don't know if because it's a `phtml` file that matters):

```
<form id="answer_form" class="form" method="post">
   <textarea class="input-text" id="content" name="content" id="answer_content" title="Content"></textarea>
   <div id="showContent"><span></span></div>
</form>
```

I want to show it's content in the `showContent` div **while** it's being typed, in other words, after every letter.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you make it jsfiddle.net ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest the use of `input` event instead of `keyup` since it's more efficient when you track the user input's :

```
$('body').on('input', '#content', function(){
    $('#showContent').text( $(this).val() );
})
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$('body').on('input', '#content', function(){
    $('#showContent').text($(this).val());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="answer_form" class="form" method="post">
  <textarea class="input-text" id="content" name="content" id="answer_content" title="Content"></textarea>
  <div id="showContent"><span></span></div>
</form>
```

Comment: I chose your answer because on('input') is instant while on('keyup') from the other answer has a small delay, can you explain me why please?

Comment: Yes that why i've adde _it's more efficient when you track the user input's_ that the difference between this two events.

Answer (score 3):

I hope it will solve your problem

```
<form id="answer_form" class="form" method="post">
            <textarea onkeyup="setContent()" class="input-text" id="content" name="content" id="answer_content" title="Content"></textarea>
            <div id="showContent"><span></span></div>
</form>

<script>
function setContent(){
       $("#showContent").html($("#content").val());
}
</script>
```

Comment: your answer also worked, thanks a lot! But for what I'm going to do the other one is better.

Comment: @RodrigoDomingues no problem happy coding :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do as follow

```
$(document).on('keyup','#content',function(){
      $("#showContent").html($(this).val());
});
```

```js
$(document).on('keyup','#content',function(){
   $("#showContent").html($(this).val());
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="answer_form" class="form" method="post">
  <textarea class="input-text" id="content" name="content" id="answer_content" title="Content"></textarea>
  <div id="showContent"><span></span></div>
</form>
```